# Goでなぜか実行がブロックされてしまいプログラムが終了しない

Tags: go, tcp

Goで投資の4本値(一定期間内の始値、高値、安値、終値、時間)の値をクライアントに送るTCPサーバを書いています。
送るデータは先頭8バイトはJSONで表された4本値の構造体のバイト数を示していて、その後に実際のJSON文字列が続く形式です。

このTCPサーバのテストのために下記のようなプログラムを書いたのですが、途中でクライアントのほうがなぜかReadをブロックしてしまい(なにか原因が他にサーバーのほうにあるのかもしれませんが...)うまく終了しません。
なぜでしょうか?
下記のテストプログラムのCandleが4本値のstructです。
サーバー側のコードもその下に記載してあります。

環境はx64 Linux, Go1.18です

###### テストプログラム

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type Candle struct {
    Count    int       `json:"Count,omitempty"`
    Open     float64   `json:"Open"`
    Close    float64   `json:"Close"`
    Low      float64   `json:"Low"`
    High     float64   `json:"High"`
    Datetime time.Time `json:"Datetime"`
}

func main() {
    data_buf := make([]byte, 1024*1024)
    server_addr := "localhost"
    port := 33333
    port_str := "33333"
    JST := time.FixedZone("JST", 9*60*60)
    cs := make([]Candle, 0, 200)
    newline_sep := strings.Split(data_csv, "\n") //data_csvはCandleの値のcsv文字列
    for _, v := range newline_sep {
        var c Candle
        comma_sep := strings.Split(v, ",")
        date_str := comma_sep[0] + " " + comma_sep[1]
        date, err := time.ParseInLocation("2006/01/02 15:04", date_str, JST)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        c.Datetime = date
        open, err := strconv.ParseFloat(comma_sep[2], 64)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        high, err := strconv.ParseFloat(comma_sep[3], 64)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        low, err := strconv.ParseFloat(comma_sep[4], 64)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        clo, err := strconv.ParseFloat(comma_sep[5], 64)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        c.Open = open
        c.Close = clo
        c.High = high
        c.Low = low
        cs = append(cs, c)
    } // ここまででサーバに送るCandleの配列を作成
    num_candle := len(cs)
    fmt.Println("num_candle ", num_candle)
    candle_chan := make(chan Candle)

    go func(server_chan chan Candle) { //サーバーを別のgo routineで起動。サーバはserver_chanからCandleを受け取ってクライアントに流す
        s := NewCandleServer(server_chan)
        s.Run(server_addr, port)
    }(candle_chan)
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(1500 * time.Millisecond)
        for _, v := range cs {
            candle_chan  len(data_buf) {
            data_buf = make([]byte, size)
        }
        fmt.Println("read hang before")
        _, err = conn.Read(data_buf)
        fmt.Println("read hang")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("payload read error:", err)
        }
        i += 1
    }
    wg.Wait()
    if i != num_candle {
        _ = fmt.Errorf("something Error")
    }
}
```

###### NewCandleServerのコード

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "investment/calc"
    "investment/kabucom3"
    "log"
    "net"
    "strconv"
    "sync"
)

type Servable interface {
    kabucom3.PositionsSuccess | calc.Candle
}

func ByteLength(b []byte) ([]byte, int) {
    buff := make([]byte, 8)
    b_len := len(b)
    b_len64 := uint64(b_len)
    for i := 0; i < 8; i++ {
        buff[i] = byte((b_len64 >> ((7 - i) * 8))) & byte(0xff)
    }
    buff = append(buff, b...)
    return buff, b_len
}

type CandleServer[T Servable] struct {
    Conns *sync.Map
    C     chan T
}

func (t *CandleServer[T]) Run(addr string, port int) {
    defer func() {
        t.Conns.Range(func(k, v any) bool {
            c := k.(*net.Conn)
            (*c).Close()
            return true
        })
    }()
    go func() {
        var c int = 0
        for {
            select {
            case v := <-t.C:
                c += 1
                fmt.Println("candle_server", "case", c)
                b, err := json.Marshal(v)
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println("hang ", err)
                }
                result_buff, _ := ByteLength(b)
                t.Conns.Range(func(k, v any) bool {
                    c := k.(*net.Conn)
                    _, err := (*c).Write(result_buff)
                    if err != nil {
                        (*c).Close()
                        t.Conns.Delete(k)
                    }
                    return true
                })
                fmt.Println("candle_server", "after range")
            }
        }
    }()
    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", addr+":"+strconv.Itoa(port))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Listen Error", err)
    }
    for {
        conn, err := ln.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("Accept Error", err)
        }
        t.Conns.Store(&conn, struct{}{})
    }

}

func NewCandleServer[T Servable](c chan T) *CandleServer[T] {
    return &CandleServer[T]{C: c, Conns: &sync.Map{}}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

io.ReaderのRead(buff)メソッドはbuffサイズ分の受信が完了するまでブロックします。
送信側でそれより短い送信内容だとReadが完了することがありません。

JSONのデコード結果を受け取るのにストリーミングデコーダーが標準で用意されています。

```golang
var result map[string]interface{}
if err := json.NewDecorder(conn).Decode(&result); err != nil {
  エラーハンドリング
}
```

この方法ならJSONとして解釈できるまでストリームをReadします。